# DB2 JDBC native driver issues with lazy close

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am using java 1.5 on AS400 with DB2 database.
I am using the native JDBC driver (com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver)  to perform the connection to the database.
I want to turn "lazy close" property on to improve performance, but when I do so I get a warning, and can't see that this property was affected at all.
My connection string is:  jdbc:db2:B10D8A81/B3V0530DB2;lazy close=true;
This connection string is working fine accept the lazy close is not turned on.
The lazy close property was taken form:[ibm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fjdbcproperties.htm), maybe it's not supported with the native driver?

The warning message that I'm getting is: 
1i1f3d08dmpspwc16lpm31|596a596a, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:db2:B10D8A81/B3V0530DB2;lazy close=true;, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 3600, maxPoolSize -> 50, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> SELECT 1 FROM RIDUMMY, properties -> {user=*****, password=*****}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> true, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
04 Jan 2011 18:32:53,648  INFO SQLWarnings:43 - Extra connection property is ignored.
com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2JDBCWarning: Extra connection property is ignored.
    at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.handleURLProcessing(DB2Driver.java:1502)
    at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:1026)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
04 Jan 2011 18:32:53,759  INFO SQLWarnings:43 - Extra connection property is ignored.
com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2JDBCWarning: Extra connection property is ignored.
    at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.handleURLProcessing(DB2Driver.java:1502)
    at com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:1026)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
04 Jan 2011 18:32:53,893  INFO SQLWarnings:43 - Extra connection property is ignored.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 1):

No, this very property is not supported by the DB2 JDBC drivers. You could however look at some other [properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/doc/rjvdsprp.html), ie. queryCloseImplicit or useCachedCursor.